# SQL Server table function doesn't return values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing this table function

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_RealEstateAgentSales
    (@FirstName NVARCHAR, @SecondName NVARCHAR, @LastName NVARCHAR)
RETURNS @salesAmoutAndAgent TABLE (FirstName NVARCHAR(25),
                                   SecondName NVARCHAR(25),
                                   LastName NVARCHAR(25),
                                   sales INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sales INT;
    SET @sales = COUNT(*);

    INSERT @salesAmoutAndAgent
        SELECT @FirstName, @SecondName, @LastName, @sales
        FROM Purchases AS P
        INNER JOIN Employees AS E ON P.DealMadeByEmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
        WHERE 
            @FirstName = FirstName 
            AND @SecondName = SecondName 
            AND @LastName = LastName

    RETURN
END
```

and I want it to return the firstName, secondName, lastName and sales made depending on his first, second and last name...

But when I call it

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.RealEstatudf_eAgentSales('somename', 'somename', 'somename');
```

it returns an empty table... what is my mistake?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. If you use *only* `NVARCHAR` - then you get a string of ***EXACTLY 1 character length*** which is *usually* not what you want..... provide a reasonable length for your parameters!

Comment: @marc_s . . . That would explain the problem.  You should provide a fuller explanation as an answer.

Comment: It's hard to tell without data. A lot of things can make the query return the data. There could be one of the conditions not true or the inner join makes the result empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some errors in your code that you can check below

**REMARKS**

1. In your description you placed the call to the function with the name *RealEstatudf_eAgentSales* and it should really be *udf_RealEstateAgentSales* according to your example.
2. You must **assign the size** for the parameters of type NVARCHAR. They were without size and I assigned a 25 for example.
3. The **COUNT** aggregate function, you must include it in your query and you can avoid having to create a variable.
4. The order in the `WHERE` section should be changed. First the field and then the parameter. However, it is not a mistake as you currently have it, but it is a bad practice.
5. I leave you the code I used, the enhanced function and some **examples**

Code:

```
--Purchases
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Purchases]') AND TYPE IN (N'U'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Purchases
END

CREATE TABLE Purchases 
(
    PurchaseID INT IDENTITY
    , DealMadeByEmployeeID INT
    , PurchaseValue MONEY
)

INSERT INTO Purchases ( DealMadeByEmployeeID, PurchaseValue )
VALUES                 ( 1,                    250.15        )
,                      ( 2,                    15.50         )
,                      ( 1,                    100           )
,                      ( 1,                    300.15        )
,                      ( 2,                    500.15        )


SELECT *
FROM Purchases


--Employees
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Employees]') AND TYPE IN (N'U'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Employees
END

CREATE TABLE Employees 
(
    EmployeeID INT IDENTITY
    , FirstName VARCHAR(50)
    , SecondName VARCHAR(50)
    , LastName VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO Employees ( FirstName, SecondName, LastName )
VALUES                 ( 'J',       'E',        'P'      )
,                      ( 'Mitko',   '',         'Z'      )


SELECT *
FROM Employees
GO
```

Now the function should be like this:

```
--FUNCTION
DECLARE @strSQL nvarchar(1000)
IF EXISTS (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[udf_RealEstateAgentSales]'))
BEGIN
    SET @strSQL = 'DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_RealEstateAgentSales]'
    EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION udf_RealEstateAgentSales 
    (@FirstName NVARCHAR(25)      -- Missed length
    , @SecondName NVARCHAR(25)    -- Missed length
    , @LastName NVARCHAR(25)      -- Missed length
    )
RETURNS @salesAmoutAndAgent TABLE (
    FirstName NVARCHAR(25)
    , SecondName NVARCHAR(25)
    , LastName NVARCHAR(25)
    , sales INT
    )
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT @salesAmoutAndAgent
    SELECT @FirstName
        , @SecondName
        , @LastName
        , COUNT(*) AS Sales
    FROM Purchases AS P
        INNER JOIN Employees AS E
            ON P.DealMadeByEmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName
        AND SecondName = @SecondName
        AND LastName = @LastName

    RETURN

END

GO
```

a. Employee somename

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_RealEstateAgentSales('somename','somename','somename')
```

->

```
FirstName                 SecondName                LastName                  sales
------------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -----------
somename                  somename                  somename                  0

(1 row(s) affected)
```

b. Employee J E P

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_RealEstateAgentSales('J','E','P');
```

->

```
FirstName                 SecondName                LastName                  sales
------------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -----------
J                         E                         P                         3

(1 row(s) affected)
```

c. Employee Mitko Z

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_RealEstateAgentSales('Mitko','','Z');
```

->

```
FirstName                 SecondName                LastName                  sales
------------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -----------
Mitko                                               Z                         2

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I hope you find it useful

Comment: @marc_s Thank you so much for your help and Thanks for improving my answer! I want to ask you why do you delete de line with "GO" instruction? I wrote it beacause I get the error message: CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch. For that reason I left the GO batch separator after the DROP FUNCTION block.

Comment: Sorry, that was unintentional - added them back where needed

Comment: @marc_s Oh well! I thought it was some mistake or rule I did not know. Thank you

Comment: In a great many cases, the `GO` is not needed, and since it's not really a SQL statement (but just a delimiter in SQL Server Management Studio), I tend to try to trim the use of `GO` to the needed minimum. A `CREATE FUNCTION` statement is one of those few cases where you must have a `GO` before it, in a longer script

Answer (score 2):

First of all: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `(n)varchar` variables and parameters that you use. If you use `NVARCHAR` - then you get a string of **EXACTLY** 1 character length which is *usually* not what you want..... provide a reasonable length for your parameters! Otherwise, your value `somename` passed in the call is being truncated to just `s` .....

Next: you're selecting but you're using the **parameter names** (with the leading `@`) - not the columns names - that won't work.

And thirdly: your `WHERE` clause is all wrong - you need to write it

```
WHERE (column name) = @(parameter name)
```

Try this code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_RealEstateAgentSales
    (@FirstName NVARCHAR(25),
     @SecondName NVARCHAR(25), 
     @LastName NVARCHAR(25) )
RETURNS @salesAmoutAndAgent TABLE (FirstName NVARCHAR(25),
                                   SecondName NVARCHAR(25),
                                   LastName NVARCHAR(25),
                                   sales INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sales INT;
    SET @sales = COUNT(*);

    INSERT @salesAmoutAndAgent
        SELECT 
            FirstName, SecondName, LastName, sales
        FROM 
            Purchases AS P
        INNER JOIN 
            Employees AS E ON P.DealMadeByEmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
        WHERE 
            FirstName = @FirstName 
            AND SecondName = @SecondName 
            AND LastName = @LastName

    RETURN
END
```

Also: that line

```
SET @sales = COUNT(*);
```

really doesn't make any sense at all - you need to rethink (and re-code) this to something more meaningful.... You're counting **from what table**? You definitely need **AT LEAST** a `FROM (table name)` , and most likely also some reasonable `WHERE` clause......

Comment: it kindda worked thanks... but I want every agent to be in a the same column... now i get `somename somename somename 1 somename somename somename 1` .. 2 times.. PS you missed a @ before sales in the select clause

Comment: @MitkoZ: please provide useful **input** data and **expected output** in that case!

Comment: I want for example to get an output `John Oliver Stone 2`  (the number is the number of times the where statement meets this condition)

Comment: i want the same names to appear in one column properly counted... for this example 2